# Custom product fields in wp e-Commerce plugin

Tags: custom-field, e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I want the user to be able to set a text, option values or other type of data in each product just before they add it to the cart. Just like product options.

> For example: The user buys a sticker and is able to set the text to be print

I can't use product variations for this task before it is not about fixed values. Is there a way to add this type of functionality on wp e-Commerce plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WPEC Personalize plugin from here http://www.derekweathersbee.com/products/wpec-personalize

It should do your job.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-products-designer/7818029. I used it for some clients and i think it can get the job done.